# Customising UiPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

In my objective c project I need to implement custom picker view. By implementing the default iOS picker view it look like the Wheel is rotating along a sphere.i needs just move the content vertically up and down not like sphere how to implement this.

[image]

Comment: You can use `UITableView` and there you have to manage the selection like picker.

Comment: but the content look like date picker. any way to remove the curving like sphere from picker view.

Comment: No there is no way you can change that curvature as far as I know... you've to create your own...

Comment: Maybe check this: https://medium.com/@filipealva/pickerview-your-customizable-alternative-to-uipickerview-60e0b622ad9f

Answer (score -2):

return 'UITableview':

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)theView{
return aTableView;}
```